Detect if a blackbox 24V circuit is closed using a Raspberry Pi
I want to use a Raspberry Pi to detect if a switch in a 24V circuit is closed an thus current is flowing in the circuit. The device that should be enabled by pressing the switch is an electromagnet that has about 22 Ohm resistance and is therefore running with roughly a 1A current. In particular I have the following setup:

The parts inside the green box (electromagnet, switch and the wire inbetween) are not accessible to me. Switching times are on the order of 0.5 seconds.
I already took a look at this post utilizing an optocoupler, but I could not figure out how to wire this up without limiting the current through the 22 Ohm device.
Is there a way to detect if the electromagnet is on?

I don't see how the opto circuit that you cited could help you if you cannot access anything inside the green perimeter. Basically, the only thing you can access is the power supply. Maybe if you could sense the current... https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/current-sensors/525

The standard solution is to place a low ohm high accuracy resistor in series and then measure current across it with a (high side) current sense op amp. I think some parts come with built-in resistors these days.

detect the electromagnet magnetic field ... a reed switch might work


Is there a way to detect if the electromagnet is on?

There is a way to detect if the appropriate current is flowing into the black box and, that should be enough to imply the electromagnet is on (barring some internal fault).
I'd use a hall-effect sensor for this typically but, you can use a small value resistor (below 0.1 Ω) as a current shunt with an op-amp amplifying the voltage across it.
Either method can be used in conjunction with a comparator to produce a digital signal that can be read by the Raspberry Pi.

thank you for giving these options.
so I found the INA219 board. Do you think this would be suitable?

@Mathias it looks like it could do the job but, so could an op-amp and comparator however, if you want an SPI interface then it's a contender.
